# Need to inflate one custom layout into view of another custom layout

Tags: android

I want to inflate 1 complex layout in another custom listview's one layout.
How can i achieve that?
Please i need help
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LayoutInflater` to inflate layouts. Use [`addView()`](http://goo.gl/pXGNw) to add an inflated layout to some other parent.